# Applying Work Item template to an existing work item

Tags: tfs, workitem

I used the Process Editor to create a new State for User Story work items (the state of Proposed).  When I create a new story it works fine, the User Story is created and the initial state is Proposed, just like I want it.

However when I open an existing User Story work item (one created before I made the change), it doesn't have the Proposed state as an option, and furthermore it will not accept it if I type Proposed in the State field.

Does this mean that any changes made to a Work Item Template will only apply for new work items going forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposed state is not in the dropdown, most likely because there is no transition from the current state of the work item to the proposed state.

Could you verify this?

Comment: That is correct.  In the new flow, Proposed is the initial state.

Comment: I suppose this means that I should provide a transition back to the Proposed from Active?

Comment: Yes, if you could just add a transition from Active to Proposed you are fine. When you are done with the conversion of the current work items you can remove the transition again.